# Hierarchical Types in Simple CRUD Database App

Tags: database, forms, inheritance, crud

I want to build a simple app (probably in MS Access) for a simple small-business database.  We have fairly typical entities -- customer, contact, worker, supplier, sub-contractor.  These are all variations of some hypothetical parent class, e.g. person.  Is it worth it to try to reflect this hierarchy in the tables and forms used by such an app?  How would we do that?  Master table of people with extension tables for each category related to it?  Form for people with some kind of sub-form for the extensions?  Or just forget all that and code similar but different forms and tables for each specific kind of entity?  This is definitely not worth major amount of work or rocket science.  Any standard solution out there that I can follow to get a little extra bang for the buck?

Comment: Get an open source CRM solution and tweak it to your needs.  You'll spend way too much time building the foundation instead of focusing on the parts that would make it unique to your business.

Comment: Totally agree. Free-of-charge MS SQL Server Express Edition is better alternative to MS Access also.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a desktop application.. then my best bet is on [RocketFramework](http://rocketframework.codeplex.com/).

It is free great library solid enough to develop even an enterprise scale system.. so it is  big YES for you..